# How to pass a request from one apache server to another

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have two Apache Servers with `mod_proxy` enabled. I want to know how to "pass the request" from "Apache Server A" to "Apache Server B" using the same port (`80`).

In `server A` with internal ip: `192.168.0.5` I have configured DNS and I am also using it as my mail server.

In `server B` with internal ip: `192.168.0.10` I have my own cloud server.

Today when I access `wwww.mydomain.com` or `www.mydomain.com/webmail` everything works because the content is all in `server A`, what I need is when somebody tries to access `owncloud.mydomain.com` they can access my `server B` without redirecting them to another port like `owncloud.mydomain.com:81`, I just want to use port `80`.

Actually I get a redirect loop because when I try to redirect I guess `server A` is getting the same request by himself. I have set my virtualhost working in the same `server A` what I want is to "redirect" to another server using the same port and URL (`owncloud.mydomain.com`).

I don't want to redirect using another port.

Comment: Example from Atlassian https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/using-apache-with-mod_proxy-173669.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're going to want to do something like this on Server A:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName owncloud.mydomain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.10:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.10:80/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Depending on your application you may need to make use of one or all of the following:

- X-Forwarded-For - The IP address of the client.
- X-Forwarded-Host - The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
- X-Forwarded-Server - The hostname of the proxy server.

Take a look at the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more tips and tricks.

#### References

- [Using Apache with virtual hosts and mod_proxy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+virtual+hosts+and+mod_proxy)
- [Apache Module mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: It works. But i have another trouble, the owncloud server is in owncloud.mydomain.com/owncloud, how can i "redirect" to that path /owncloud. 
Now i have this in my server A:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^owncloud\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
                RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ http://owncloud.mydomain.com/$1  [P]


How can i redirect to /owncloud

THanks

Comment: I'd ask it as another question.

Comment: Here you have the question:  http://serverfault.com/questions/511191/mod-proxy-proxy-and-redirect-to-specific-path